# Authenticate a rest api using keycloak access token in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, postman

I have created a rest api in node js and used keycloak-connect npm packge. I have mapped the nodejs middleware with keycloak middleware.

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var app = express();
var Keycloak = require('keycloak-connect');
var keycloak =new Keycloak();

app.use( keycloak.middleware( {
logout: '/logout',
admin: '/',
} ));

router.get('/users',function(req, res, next) {
var token=req.headers['authorization']; //Access token received from front end

//Now how to authenticate this token with keycloak???

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
router.get('/shop',keycloak.protect(),function(req, res, next) {

});
```